# Calculation of Analytic image using 2D Hilbert transform

Tags: image-processing, frequency-domain, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal

I am working on a problem of phase (/phase derivative) retrieval from **closed fringe patterns**. The paper https://opg.optica.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-58-16-4420&id=413113 which uses a pseudo-Wigner Ville distribution (PSWVD) to directly estimate the unwrapped phase derivative is what I want to implement. 
The PSWVD method requires a complex signal (here, complex/analytic image). The authors have applied the method to holographic interferometry where one gets the complex signal by default. But I am interested in applying the method to photoelastic fringe patterns(another interferometric technique) where one gets only closed fringe patterns (i.e., real part of the complex signal). So, I need to perform real to analytic image conversion before implementing PSWVD.

For experimentation, a Gaussian phase is simulated (as shown below)

[image]

The real part of the signal exp(i*phi*) based on the simulated phase will be cos(*phi*). This is the closed fringe pattern, which is given below:

[image]

The aim is to obtain an analytic image, i.e, get the sin(*phi*) image from cos(*phi*) image using Hilbert transform to define the analytic image of the form exp(i*phi*).

After applying the 2-D Hilbert transform (available in the scipy module) on the cos(*phi*) image, the result obtained is:

[image]

This is clearly not the sin(*phi*) image. The true sin(*phi*) image is given below:
[image]

Later, I found that this is reported in literature as half plane Hilbert complex image and this real to analytic image conversion is quite involved than a simple function call.

I found that introducing spatial carrier to the real fringe pattern and then applying Hilbert transform is a possible way out. But I am not quite sure how this works as I am not from a signal processing background. I would highly appreciate it if someone can point me to the right resources concerning this (mainly on spatial carriers or single image real to analytic coversion)?

**PS:**

  ->  I have been told that phase shifting method can also be used for constructing the analytic image, but this requires multiple images to be captured experimentally. I am interested in single image real to analytic conversion for which spatial carrier fringe method was recommended.
  ->  I am aware of the closed fringe techniques that are based on iterative optimization, but since experimentally I can easily introduce a spatial carrier, I preferred this method over the others.

Comment: You want to compute the sine component, that you didn’t measure, from the cosine component. If this were possible, the sine component wouldn’t be necessary.

Comment: [An Approach to the 2D Hilbert Transform for Image Processing Applications](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221472037_An_Approach_to_the_2D_Hilbert_Transform_for_Image_Processing_Applications) may be of help in formulating an answer.